# How to approximate the numbers after finding the linear approximation?

Tags: calculus, linear-approximation

Here is the problem:

Find the linear approximation of the function 
$g(x)= \sqrt[5]{1 + x}$ at a = 0.

I found the linear approximation to be g(x) $\approx$ $\frac 15$x + 1

Use it to approximate the numbers (Round your answers to three decimal places.) :

$\sqrt[5]{0.95}$ $\approx $ 0.989 (This is what I'm currently getting)

$\sqrt[5]{1.1}$ $\approx $ 1.019 (This is what I'm currently getting)

However, I am incorrect any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\sqrt[5]{0.95}=\sqrt[5]{1+(-0.05)}=g(-0.05)\approx 1+\frac{1}{5}(-0.05)=...$

Comment: $\sqrt[5]{1.1}=\sqrt[5]{1+0.1}=g(0.1)\approx 1+\frac{1}{5}(0.1) =$ ... is this for the other one as well?

Comment: Hell yeah, totally get it now, thanks been a long day.